# sending conversion data to google ads from server code

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

usually we add a script to our website to track conversion for google analytics. Is there any way send the data from plain javascript code such as in the case of [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api#). for example:

```js
'use strict';
const bizSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-business-sdk');
const Content = bizSdk.Content;
const CustomData = bizSdk.CustomData;
const DeliveryCategory = bizSdk.DeliveryCategory;
const EventRequest = bizSdk.EventRequest;
const UserData = bizSdk.UserData;
const ServerEvent = bizSdk.ServerEvent;

const access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
const pixel_id = '<ADS_PIXEL_ID>';
const api = bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token);

let current_timestamp = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);

const userData = (new UserData())
                .setEmails(['joe@eg.com'])
                .setPhones(['12345678901', '14251234567'])
                // It is recommended to send Client IP and User Agent for Conversions API Events.
                .setClientIpAddress(request.connection.remoteAddress)
                .setClientUserAgent(request.headers['user-agent'])
                .setFbp('fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397')
                .setFbc('fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890');

const content = (new Content())
                .setId('product123')
                .setQuantity(1)
                .setDeliveryCategory(DeliveryCategory.HOME_DELIVERY);

const customData = (new CustomData())
                .setContents([content])
                .setCurrency('usd')
                .setValue(123.45);

const serverEvent = (new ServerEvent())
                .setEventName('Purchase')
                .setEventTime(current_timestamp)
                .setUserData(userData)
                .setCustomData(customData)
                .setEventSourceUrl('http://jaspers-market.com/product/123')
                .setActionSource('website');

const eventsData = [serverEvent];
const eventRequest = (new EventRequest(access_token, pixel_id))
                .setEvents(eventsData);


eventRequest.execute().then(
  response => {
    console.log('Response: ', response);
  },
  err => {
    console.error('Error: ', err);
  }
);
```

or we can do something like:
To send new events, make a POST request to this API's /events edge from this path: [https://graph.facebook.com/{API_VERSION}/{PIXEL_ID}/events?access_token={TOKEN}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BAPI_VERSION%7D/%7BPIXEL_ID%7D/events?access_token=%7BTOKEN%7D). When you post to this edge, Facebook creates new server events.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Did you find any solution?